# Win32 equivalent of getgid

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to convert some C Linux code to Win32 C++. And I have **getgid** function. How can I convert this Linux C function to Win32 ?

Here is the documentation for **getgid**: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getgid.2.html

Here is use context:

```
struct SEC_CONTEXT* scx;
scx->gid = getgid();
```

where SEC_CONTEXT is defined as:

```
struct SEC_CONTEXT {
ntfs_volume* vol;
gid_t gid; /* gid of user requesting (not the mounter) */
pid_t tid; /* thread id of thread requesting */
};
```

Furthermore, this object, **scx**, is used inside of **ntfs_mapping** function, and so on … and **git_t** is a simple **unsigned int**.

Comment: Windows doesn't have "groups" the same way that POSIX systems have, so therefore there's no equivalent function in Windows.

Comment: Then what should I put instead of getgid function ? Do I have any chance to solve this matter ?

Comment: Do you need to print "group" id at all? What is the original program doing?

Comment: The returned value of getgid is put it into a struct ... I don't know if is so critical in Win32 case ..

Comment: You are just talking about mechanics. What you *should* do instead is capture the logic. You need to answer a few questions first: What is the source application doing with that information? Can that use be transferred into a more generic concept? Can you translate that concept over to Windows? Don't write any code, before you have answers to those questions.

Comment: Since we don't know what it's for or what the program is doing, there's really no way for us to tell.

Comment: Sorry, I need to solve tones of errors, that is why I pass over few errors as mechanical. This value returned from getgid is put it into a structure and then used as parameter into ntfs_build_mapping function. This function is part of NTFS Linux library.

Comment: Still, getgid function need to return the right value, of course, for Win32.

Comment: Access control in Windows is handled vastly different from access control in *NIX systems. Chances are, you don't even need to map anything. You are on Windows. You already have a DACL. You don't need to map that to a security implementation that doesn't exist on Windows. Still, the question isn't answerable. You have to provide context.

Comment: _"... into ntfs_build_mapping function. This function is part of NTFS Linux library..."_ as NTFS is native to MS-Windows start by removing this layer ... your other problems my just disappear.

Comment: That's like asking: *"Hey, I have this code: `auto x{ foo() }; auto y{ x };`. `foo` doesn't exist in my target platform. What do I need to change?"*. This is neither answerable, nor useful. Voting to close.

Comment: I will continue to update the answer.

Comment: @Richard: "NTFS is native to MS-Windows" but how can I retrieve NTFS info about NTFS drive files ?

Comment: By using Windows' native [file management functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-management-functions) and Windows' native [access control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-control). You are trying to fix your problem by attempting to add another layer, when your solution is most likely to just remove the layer you are trying to fix altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows doesn't have the notion of a POSIX process group. Making that code portable will require understanding what the group id is used for.

As an inspiration, though, here's how GnuWin implements it:

```
/* Get the real group ID of the calling process.  */
gid_t
__getgid ()
{
  return 0;
}
```

A more helpful value is obtained by `getpgid`, because by default, windows groups the processes by the parent PID; so the group id is equal to the process id value.

Comment: getpgid has not equivalent in Win32 either ... but I guess returning 0 is ok.

Comment: @flaviu2 `getpgid` in Win32 will simply return the value passed. Or, another way, instead of `getpgid`, you can just get the pid for that process.

Comment: Then I need to a kind of GetProcessID() ? Something like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocessid ?

Comment: We don't know what you need to be doing to solve your *problem*, since you only asked about your proposed solution.

Comment: I have dome like this, I hope to be ok: scx->gid = GetProcessId(::GetCurrentProcess()); Please correct me if is wrong.

Comment: getpgid is not related to getgid.

Comment: @flaviu2 Unless you know what it actually does, your attempt to port this code will be hopeless.

Comment: I will update the original post. Thank you.